# Searching table in MySQL with PHP mysqli returns empty result for strings containing forward slash

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `mycolumn`='stringa  /stringb'
```

This query works if run directly through PHPMyAdmin or in PHP as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `eztrack` WHERE `visible`='1' AND `OrderHed_PONum`='stringa  /stringb'";
$DB->query($query); // $DB is a mysqli object
```

However, when getting a search keyword from $_GET or $_POST, it returns an empty result:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `eztrack` WHERE `visible`='1' AND `OrderHed_PONum`='" . $DB->real_escape_string($_POST['q']) . "'";
$result = $DB->query($query); // $result->num_rows is 0
```

Do forward slashes need to be escaped? If so how? And why does it work when the search keyword is pasted directly into the file? Any help would be appreciated!

**-- Edit: Solved --**

The issue was not with PHP or mysqli. It had to do with copying data from Chrome. Please see my comment below.

Comment: If you're stuffing "external" text into a query, then you have to escape all sql-metacharacters, unless you WANT it to be seen as a metacharacter. In technical terms, you're doing this all wrong. you shouldn't be escaping things yourself. You should be using prepared statements and placeholders.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks, I had tried this with prepared statements but got the same result. Just figured out it was an issue with copying search queries from Chrome :/... I was copying search keywords from Google Chrome to test. However, I believe Chrome wasn't copying spaces properly. I've tried typing search keywords and copying from Firefox and it works. I'm currently on Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 m.

Comment: Specifically, I was copying data from PHPMyAdmin in Chrome when I ran into this issue. Also, do I put this in as an answer (this my first post on SO)?

Comment: you can answer your own question. that's perfectly acceptable. just don't do it a lot, otherwise it'd be viewed as an attempt to pad your reputation score.